# Error while Sending Builds to Codename one Server

Tags: codenameone

I am getting below mentioned error very frequently at the time of sending builds to codename one server.

Building for username: myemail@gmail.com

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection
>   during handshake at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:992) at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
>   at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
>   at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
>   at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
>   at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
>   at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1513)
>   at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.access$200(HttpURLConnection.java:90)
>   at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$9.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1433)
>   at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$9.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1431)
>   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivilegedWithCombiner(AccessController.java:782)
>   at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1430)
>   at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
>   at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1045) at
>   com.codename1.build.client.BuildProcess.login(BuildProcess.java:119)
>   at
>   com.codename1.build.client.CodeNameOneBuildTask.execute(CodeNameOneBuildTask.java:249)
>   at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
>   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor85.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
>   at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348) at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435) at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456) at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
>   at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364) at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
>   at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248) at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:286)
>   at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:555)
>   at
>   org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)
>   Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly at
>   sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:505) at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973) ...
>   31 more /home/hplus/NetBeansProjects/HplusNew/build.xml:221: Error in
>   server build process BUILD FAILED (total time: 15 minutes 19 seconds)

Please advice.

Comment: By "frequently", do you mean every time?  Sometimes I'll receive errors like this when there is a network disruption.  But usually it clears it self up within a few minutes.